# what does initialLayout in appwidget-provider means?

Tags: android, widget, android-widget

`<appwidget-provider`

`android:initialLayout="@layout/appwidget_main"/>`

where is this layout (appwidget_main) used?

Answer (score 1):

what does initialLayout in appwidget-provider means?

> The AppWidgetProviderInfo defines the essential qualities of an App Widget, such as its minimum layout dimensions, its initial layout resource, how often to update the App Widget, and (optionally) a configuration Activity to launch at create-time. Define the AppWidgetProviderInfo object in an XML resource using a single  element and save it in the project's res/xml/ folder.

This is a normal layout that defines how the widget looks like on the screen.

> The initialLayout attribute points to the layout resource that defines the App Widget layout.

You create this layout on your own, like any activity/fragment layout, and reference it within the `appwidget-provider` (of the widget info XML file) to be used by the system, either when you preview the phones' widgets, or when you place it on the home screen.

Check [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets#MetaData) for more info.